# How can i Scan IP address and port in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, networking, ip, port

I want to make a app have a function that can scan the local network in a range of ip to find out which ip is opened a specified port.
for example : 192.168.1.104 : 3737
I can search it and show it in my iphone.

Actually i have searched for a long time before i ask here.I have tried many ways ,such as
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43551   (using NSStream)
and = ASIHTTPRequest

I cannot work it out in fact . Anyone can tell me the solution? or Which classes i can use?

Please help me .Please.

for the NSStream method (above one) ,it cannot work with ARC .It make me trouble.

```
if (inputStreamPtr != NULL) {
    *inputStreamPtr  = NSMakeCollectable(readStream) ;
}
if (outputStreamPtr != NULL) {
    *outputStreamPtr = NSMakeCollectable(writeStream);
}
```

It will show me failed that NSMakeCollectable is unavailable for ARC

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in `NSNetService` and `NSNetServiceBrowser`. You can publish service (with specified type and port) by `NSNetService`, and by `NSNetServiceBrowser` you can find services by specified type.

Comment: sorry , i think it is not suitable for me.actually ,i have hold up a web server with a specified port.I just want to use my iphone to scan it in local network